# Detect shape/object in an image of handdrawing

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

Given a hand-drawn image, I need to figure out what the object is and replace it with a proper drawing. Objects could be basic shapes like rectangles or circles, or simple objects like airplanes, apples, or computers. Eg:
[image]

I found a link called AutoDraw (https://www.autodraw.com/), but it only works with ink strokes. It relies on the order and exact strokes made by the user to classify the image. However, for static images, we don't have this stroke information.

Pls suggest simplest approach for the problem,I would want to avoid training CNN myself.

Comment: opencv HoughCircles? Did you think about that? Also currently your post does not include a MRE nor does it include code -> not suitable for here. If you want help from us you would need to adjust your question. please read the how to ask section